# How to set a background image in Scrollviewer in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollview, background-image

I want to set a `Background Image` to a Scrollview. The Scrollview is the root view of the app(I mean, all other views are nested to it). Is it possible to set a background image to it?

I'm building my app with `C#` and `XAML`.

Comment: Have you tried using Blend to do this?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But didn't find any Background Image option. There were options to change background color, no image.

Comment: opps! got it. problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="your_image_uri"/>
        </ScrollViewer.Background>
    </ScrollViewer>
```